# use fastjson in SSH to return result

Tags: json, ssh, struts

In ssh,when we want to return json data we can just set

`<result name="success" type="json"></result>`

in the struts xml.

But when my data has Timestamp values it return result like "2015-08-11T09:19:25Z";
 Then I want to use fastjson to treat the data(has some other reasons),but I don't know to set fastjson into ssh so that I can return a json from fastjson rather than the json util itself.

looking forward to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Above the get method of the timestamp value we can add

```
 @JSON(format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  public Timestamp getTest(){
      return this.test;
 }
```